# C++ clarification

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am doing a C++ code in Omnet++ simulator where I came across this piece of code. Can somebody please explain hpw is this sequence working ?

```
char *st = "data.enc";

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(st,std::ios_base::app); //Please provide explnation for this line 
printf("\n AES encryption:\n");
for(i=0;i<4*4;i++)
{
    printf("%02x ",out[i]+l);

    myfile <<out[i]+l<<"\n";
}

printf("%02x ",out[i]);//What is out[i] ?
myfile.close();
printf("\n\n");
```

Comment: `std::ofstream` is a standard, well documented type. Or are you asking how come a member function call is present?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: You'll have to help us on `out` it's not defined anywhere in the given code. If it's not an array (or a pointer to an array) of unsigned integers, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: You can figure out what`out[i]` is by looking at the declaration of `out`. If you still don't understand it, an introductory book would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(st,std::ios_base::app); //Please provide explnation for this line
```

Opens the file in append mode. That means that insertions will be appended to the end of the file instead of overwriting it.

```
for(i=0;i<4*4;i++)
{
    printf("%02x ",out[i]+l);

    myfile <<out[i]+l<<"\n";
}
```

Takes the 16 first elements in out and:

```
printf("%02x ",out[i]+l);
```

Prints them in hexadecimal format as if they were bytes. The `0` means fill with 0s until reaching the desired length (2). `x` means print in hexadecimal.

```
myfile <<out[i]+l<<"\n";
```

Appends the contents of out adding 1.

```
printf("%02x ",out[i]);//What is out[i] ?
```

Prints out[16] (this time without adding one) in 2 digit hexadecimal format.

```
myfile.close();
```

Closes the file.

```
printf("\n\n");
```

Prints two blank lines.

Comment: Thank you all for your explnation. So now I am wondering from where my file is reading the values and writting in it. Any findings pls ?

Comment: std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(st,std::ios_base::app);